# Pydantic, nested clases

Tags: python, pydantic

I have two validation models in pydantic and one is an optional field of the second. How can initialize the first object?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime

class FistObj(BaseModel):
  arg1: str
  arg2: str
  arg3: str


class GeneralObj(BaseModel):
  var1: str
  var2: str
  first_obj : Optional[FistObj] = None 
  created: Optional[datetime.datetime] = None
  
  model_config = ConfigDict(extra='forbid', validate_assignment=True)
```

```py
def create_objects():
  args = {"var1": "aa", "var2":"bb"}
  general_obj = GeneralObj(**args)
  # some checks that returns dictionary other_data
  other_data = {"arg1":"1", "arg2":"2", "arg3":"3"}
  my_fisrt_obj = FirstObj(**other_data)
  now = datetime.now()
  # try to add my_fisrt_obj to general_obj
  general_obj.first_obj = my_fisrt_obj
  #try to add created value
  general_obj.created=now
```

The output is that two last assigments are None, and I want them to be the objects already initialized. Is there a way to do that?

```
 # try to add my_fisrt_obj to general_obj
  general_obj.first_obj = my_fisrt_obj
  #try to add created value
  general_obj.created=now
```